# jQuery + GWT set checkbox status

Tags: jquery, gwt, mobile, input, checkbox

Using the UI:Binder.

The checkboxes are implemented as following:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<input type="checkbox" ui:field="uniqueID" class="custom" />
<label for="uniqueID"><ui:text from="{res.text}"></ui:text></label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

And
`checkboxNewsletter.setId("uniqueID");`, because unfortunately you cannot set ui:field and ID simultaneously.

I tried to set the checkboxes with

```
@UiField InputElement checkbox;
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

Which didn't work. So i tried JSNI to access the jQuery-JS directly:

```
public static native void setCheckBoxStatus(String id, Boolean isChecked)/*-{
        $wnd.jQuery('input[name='+id+']').attr('checked', isChecked);
}-*/;
```

...which didn't work out much better.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this? 
jQuery seems to override the GWT checkbox; the generated HTML is kinda weird and seems to consist of two checkbox-elements. You can see the original (and correctly checked) element when deleting the jQuery overlay.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing jQuery and GWT is a bad idea! With GWT you should primarily be working with Java code against the GWT DOM APIs. You are right that you cannot set an ID and a `ui:field` on an element via the UIBinder, but this is not the root cause of your problem.

The code snippet you provided for your view would not compile. You need to specify a field with the annotation as follows:

```
@UiField
CheckBox checkbox;
```

Then within the body of a method, set the checked state:

```
// setValue sets the checked state, true = checked, false = unchecked.
checkbox.setValue(true);
```

Comment: setValue is basically the same as setChecked, already tried that (CheckBox as well as InputElement) of course. The problem here is that jQuery seems to kinda override the GWT-internal checkboxes with HTML/CSS of jQuery. Hence, the setValue-methods won't properly appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using GWT with jQuery, you should use [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) (http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/ ), which wrapps the functionality of jQuery and you can access it directly in your java code. However the this doesn't help you with the UiBinder.

This is how you define a checkbox with GWT UiBInder:

```
<g:CheckBox ui:field="uniqueID"></g:CheckBox>
```

in you uiBinder xml file and

```
@UiField 
CheckBox uniqueID;
```

in you code behing.

If you are using eclipse, you can use the designer to drag and drop the differnet elements in your layout and define the different elements togehter. This article discribes the different features of UiBinder.

PS: if you want your checkbox to be check at inizialsation you can write: `<g:CheckBox checked="true" ui:field="uniqueID"></g:CheckBox>`